# Scrapy crawl error: [Error 123]The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scrapy

I am programming using scrapy in windows, and I am entering in command

> C:\Users\David>cd c:\python27\natliq

which is the path where I have my spider. However, when I take my spider for a test run by running the crawl command I am getting the following error.

> File "C:\python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode)
>
> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'c:\python27\natliq'

I have not typed in a double backslash. So I guess my question is where scrapy or windows  is getting this error from. But how to fix it?

FYI, I have tested my spider on Saturday and it worked. Now all of a sudden I am facing this message and have no clue how to resolve.

**Spider Code:**

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from natliq.items import NatliqItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from PIL import Image


class NatliqSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "natliq"
    allowed_domain = [""]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.yachtauctions.com/inventory/"
    ]

rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths = ('//td/a[3] [@class="inv-link"]'),
            attrs = ('href'),
            ),
        follow=True,
        callback = 'item_parse',
        ),
    )
def item_parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="content-area"]/div[@class="listing"]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = NatliqItem()
        item['price'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['status'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['stock_number'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['vessel_type'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[4]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['year'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[5]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['make'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[6]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['model'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[7]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['description'] = site.select('//table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[11]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['has_engine'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['numberOfEngines'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['engine_make'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[4]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['engine_model'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[5]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['fuel_type'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[6]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['engine_hp'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[7]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['engine_hours'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[8]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['location'] = site.select('//div[2]/table[@class="inv-table"]/tr[14]/td[2]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        # item['image_urls'] = ["http://www.yachtauctions.com" + x for x in site.select('//ul[@class="thethumbs"]/li/a/@href').extract()[0].strip()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Post your source. What version of Scrapy and Python are you running?

Comment: Try using raw strings. The \n may be the source of the error.

Comment: As @SukritKalra said, isn't the "\n" in 'c:\python27\natliq' interpreted as     "c:\python27" + <newline> + "atliq"? have you changed your spider location to "natliq" folder after saturday?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and scrapy 0.16.2. No I have not changed the spider location and I have ran the code with c:\python27\natliq and it scraped the data successfully I still have the data in my CSV file. How do I enter it in a raw string?

Comment: Is `c:\python27\natliq` has the `spiders` folder, `items.py`, `pipelines.py` and `settings.py`? To try `scrapy list`, what's the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that the issue was with the n in \natliq looks like its some type of command in windows CMD so it gets confuesd and throws the error. I have recreated the project naming the folder and spider starting with an L this time and now it is working.